# Javascript closures, 'this' keyword and variable namespaces

Tags: javascript, closures, this, naming

I'm trying to understand how the `this` keyword works.

This article [The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) states

"In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of."

```
function someClosure() {
    var myVal0, myVal1, myVal2;

    init = function (myVal0, myVal1, myVal2) {

        myVal0 = myVal0;
        this.myVal1 = myVal1;
        this.myVal2 = myVal2;

    };

    getMyVal0 = function() { return myVal0 };
    getMyVal1 = function() { return myVal1 }
    getMyVal2 = function() { return this.myVal2 }
};
```

I surmise that `getMyVal0` is `undefined` after `init()` is called because of a naming clash (the assignment is ambiguous).

But (after calling `init()`) why does `getMyVal1` return `undefined`? The reference to `myVal1` should not be ambiguous. Does Javascript require an explicit use of `this`? `getMyVal2` returns the expected value, but again, I'm surprised that I need the explicit `this`.

Please clarify this behavior.

Ultimately, I'm trying to establish a naming convention for function arguments when initializing member variables. By industry convention, IRR is IRR and it seems `this` should allow me to avoid comming up with two names for a variable (without always referencing the member variable with `this`.) What's the convention for doing what I want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by [IRR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRR)?

Comment: @Pointy IRR = "internal rate of return". I mean by my industry convention, IRR is used as a variable name. The intent is to avoid IRR1, IRR2 if possible.

Comment: You realize that by not declaring `init` and the `getMyVal` functions with `var` that you're creating **global** variables, right?

Comment: Also, if you find yourself wanting to have numbered variations on the same name, you probably want an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) at MDN.

The value of `this` depends on how you call the function. But you don't call the `init` at all, and all variables are still `undefined`.

> By industry convention, `this` should allow me to avoid comming up with two names for a variable

No. `this` in JavaScript is different from `this` in other languages like Java. It will not let you access variables from a higher scope. In your case, the arguments of the `init` function just shadow the variables from `myClosure` - you can't access them. You need to rename them if you want them. Use this script:

```
var init, getMyVal; // global, or at least "outer", variables

function closure() {
    var myVal, myVal2; // scoped to the closure

    // all the following function can access them
    init = function(val, myVal2) {
        myVal = val; // assign the argument to the closure variable
        // myVal2 === myVal2 - sorry, this only refers to the argument
    };
    getMyVal = function() {
        return myVal; // get the closure variable
    };
};
closure(); // execute it - you might also have used a immediately-executing function

init("some value");

getMyVal(); // "some value"
```

Btw, you might combine the `closure` and `init` call to only one function:

```
var getMyVal;
function initClosure(myVal) {
    // the argument is scoped to this function, like a var declaration

    getMyVal = function() { return myVal; };
}
initClosure("some value");

getMyVal(); // "some value"
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clearer. `init()` is being called. I don't know if that impacts your answer. I edited my question.

Comment: OK, I added a commented example script. To clarify: the `this` has a very different approach and nothing to do with scopes.

Answer (score 3):

Well PPK is simply incorrect in that article. The `this` pointer has a value that is determined anew with **each function call**.  There is no such thing as "method ownership" in JavaScript.  The `this` pointer gets a value when a method is invoked as a result of an object property reference, that's true, but the same method can be a property of many different objects.

Aside from that, it's important to understand that local variables in a constructor function are completely distinct from object properties of an object `this` refers to.  That is,

```
function Constructor() {
  var x, y;

  x = "whatever";
}
```

In that code, the variables "x" and "y" are local variables, and **not** properties of an object.

Comment: Agreed, that PPK article deserves a healthy dose of garbage collection. If "ownership" wasn't bad enough, we're then provided with a fantastical treatise on "copying".

Answer (score 3):

The `var` keyword in ECMAscript 2-6-2 3rd edition aswell as in ES5 pretty much only says, "*declare that variable in the current context*". `this` on the other side always refers to the "*object of invocation*" (how I like to call it), which is a different story.

The `context` for a function is not directly accessible through Javascript itself, its only existent in the underlaying `lexicalEnvironment` (ES5) or the `Execution Context -> Activation Object` (ES3).

So, by explicitly calling `this.xxx` you are reading and writting to the OOI (which can change, based on **how** the method was called). The `"Activation Object"` holds

- formal parameters
- variables declared by `var`
- function declarations

All of those things are **not** stored in the object which is referred by `this`.